# Initial price at Recurring Payments Button of PayPal Payments Standard

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

How can I add Initial Price to subscription that is created using PayPal Payments Standard?

I do not want to define this value as "Trial Period Price", because it will mislead my customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything specific to initial price in the Standard Subscription variables.  I know Express Checkout and Recurring Payments gives you that ability, though.